# OpenSSL ssl routines::no protocol available when running curl on Windows

Tags: curl, tls1.0

Attempting to execute this curl command on Windows legacy (2012) to use TLS 1.0 as follows:

```
curl -v -i --tlsv1.0 --tls-max 1.0 https://localhost:8443
```

And I get this error:

OpenSSL 3.1.0: error 0A0000BF::SSL routines::no protocols available. I have tried modifying the openssl configuration by adding this at the end.

```
[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0
```

and this

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init
```

at the very top but this did not help. It is almost as if TLS 1.0 support has been completely removed from this version of curl (8.1.2).

Any thoughts?